# Two linear regulators from a single buck converter

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, switching, linear-regulator

I have a switching regulator giving 12V and 5 amperes maximum current,and I have a CW7805 linear regulator IC (5v 1.5A ) at its output. The problem is due to my circuit taking almost 1 amp of current, the power dissipation is almost 7 watts. Even the 2.1x2.5 cm heatsink gets hot.

I cannot lower the switching voltage as I need to drive led strips from the 12 volts.  What are my choices? Can I join the outputs of the two CW7805 ICs and connect them in parallel, or should I just connect both the grounds and power components seperately to share the current between them,
or should I add a 9V linear regulator in between the two so that dissipation is less?

Another thing I wanted to add is that the switching regulator is being powered from a switch mode powersupply, so I imagine adding a third switching regulator (instead of the linear regulator) would probably give some crazy effect on the outputs.

Comment: What's the thermal resistance of that heatsink? What temperature rise did you calculate for it, and what temp rise is allowable in your application? It seems likely you need to re-calculate, and choose a bigger heatsink.

Comment: I think around 60 C is fine but i am getting around 80-90 C from the heatsink. Sorry my heatsink doesnt have a thermal resistance value. I forgot to mention, i also have a fan attached to cool the heatsink further,.

Comment: Live with it or buck from 12 to 5.

Comment: There is no explicit reason that you can not use another buck regulator to go from 12V to 5V.

Comment: I agree with others: generate 5V with a switching regulator not a linear regulator. Multiple switchers in a design is the norm, not crazy. If you're concerned about 5V cleanliness you can instead generate about 6V with a switcher and then LDO down to 5V from there.

Comment: Excellent Advice!, I'll try it out!